# How do I handle clicks in a ListView that keeps being updated?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, buttonclick

I have a simple Activity with a `ListView` that can be refreshed with a swipe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scan_main_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_refresher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/scan_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        </ListView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The ListView's items contain a few simple text areas and a button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <!-- define text areas -->
    [...]

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cdc_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Button"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**My problem is that the button clicks do not consistently register.** Sometimes the `OnClickListener` fires properly, sometimes it doesn't.

I've found that the culprit is the `Adapter`'s `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but I don't know exactly why, and even though I can reduce the amount of calls to reduce the bug frequency, it's not a proper solution.

In the following code, the bug appears only when `loopNotifyDataChanged()` is called.

In the `Activity` :

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    loopNotifyDataChanged()
}

fun loopNotifyDataChanged() {
    runOnUiThread {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        scanTimer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                loopNotifyDataChanged()
            }
        }, 100)
    }
}
```

And in the `ListView`'s `Adapter`

```
override fun getView(i: Int, view: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup): View {
    val viewHolder: ViewHolder?
    var mutableView = view

    // create the view and viewHolder or recover the view
    [...]

    // Set the button onClickListeners
    mutableView!!.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Clicked list $i", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        color = if (color == Color.GREEN) Color.MAGENTA else Color.GREEN
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    viewHolder.cdcButton.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Clicked button $i", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        color = if (color == Color.RED) Color.BLUE else Color.RED
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    // Update the button color
    viewHolder.cdcButton.setBackgroundColor(color)

    // Update the textViews
    [...]
}
```

*Notes: I know the swipe refresh looks useless here but it's needed in the real application for starting a bluetooth scan, not notify a data change. I included it just in case it does have an importance.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using listView.setOnItemClickListener instead of button.setOnClickListener ?

Comment: I have tried it, but it's worse. The button bug is still here but I can no longer click the views at all